# How to publish algorithm

Tags: online-publication

I have a new algorithm which I would like to publish.

I'm not a student, so I wanted to know a few things:
1) What should I publish? Just the algorithm with explanation? an academic paper? What are the principals of writing such one?
2) Where to publish?
3) What are the outcomes of publishing the algorithm? Legally or any other aspects I should be aware of.

Any other tips and helpful things I should know will be welcomed

Comment: Why do you want to publish? What's your objective here?

Comment: To let other know\make use\enhance the algorithm, and to get recognition on it.

Comment: You could put the code on github to achieve "letting others know/enhance/getting recognition"

Answer (score 5):

Making an algorithm public is easy: you can put it on your webpage. By having it published as an academic paper (either conference or journal), you can  get reviews, which is interesting. Reviewers may help you evaluate the novelty of your approach. I thus suggest a paper, with at least:

- a motivation for your algorithm,
- a review of the related approaches and the explanation for its novelty,
- the algorithm with explanations.

It is always a plus if you implement it also in a common computer language, so that others can check its efficiency, find bugs, allow improved versions. A working version of your algorithm in the shape of a code (compilable with instructions) can be put on [GitHub](https://github.com/) for instance, for better versioning.

There are several [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) related journals and conferences, for instance at the ACM Society:

- [ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software](http://toms.acm.org/)
- [ACM Transactions on Algorithms](http://talg.acm.org/)

and you can easily find many more, depending on the subfield your algorithm belong (combinatorics, optimization, real-time computing, etc.). Some are listed at the [List of computer science conferences: Algorithms and theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_science_conferences#Algorithms_and_theory).

Comment: Conferences are the primary venue for disseminating research in algorithms, not journals.  See, for example, [SODA](https://www.siam.org/meetings/da17/).

Comment: @JeffE True. When I wrote "published as an academic paper", I had in mind conferences too, because they often count as "papers". In computer vision, machine learning, many conferences indeed publish algorithmic papers

Comment: To @LaurentDuval - If algorithm is published as academic paper in journal (as version 1.0), is it possible to later publish its new upgraded version? (2.0, 3.0 etc.) ? Would the editors of mathematical/IT journals make a complain that it is "not novel enough" ? Do you have any experience with such scenario?

Comment: I cannot say for all algorithms. But this happens often in optimization, and for instance with the [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/#documentation). Of course, editors can complain, however if the novel version is shown more efficient, with better convergence, implement in parallel, formally proven.  Maybe a short note could be good enough for a V2.0

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go for [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/). However, you cannot just publish a plain algorithm. You need to format your document as a research paper. [This](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/tools/report/reportform.html) link might give you an idea of what to include.